# Jquery ajax Delete retrieves 500 error in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to incorporate jquery ajax in my project, when i'm trying to delete a record i obtain a  500 (Internal Server Error).

my code

```
  <a href="javascript:checkDelete({{$model->id}});">Delete Model </a>
```

js

```
<script>


    function checkDelete(id) {
        if (confirm('Really want to delete?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: '/admin/models/' + id,
                success: function(result) {
                    //
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

my routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('admin/posts', 'PostsController');
    Route::resource('admin/models', 'ModelsController');
    Route::resource('admin/models.pictures', 'PicturesController');
    Route::resource('admin/models.videos', 'VideosController');
    Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('admin/ayuda', function() {
        return View::make('admin.ayuda');
    });
});
```

Comment: The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Can we see your route?

Comment: I edited to show my routes

Comment: Ok I changed the "DELETE" with "POST"  and now i'm getting a 404... so i must be passing bad the url in my js function

Answer (score -3):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/admin/models/' + id,
    success: function(result) {
         //
    }
});
```

Comment: that's returns ok! when I alert on the success function, but doesn't delete the record from the database

Comment: Well you should take a look at your php code logic.

Comment: Never ever do any delete anything using GET. Ever. -1. GET is not supposed to change anything.

Comment: An answer ought to have a bit of explanation too, just plain code snippet is not a very good answer.